# ٩(●̮̮̃•̃)۶ Forbid unicode?

Tags: discussion, markdown, unicode

Should we forbid Unicode characters completely/partially/or not at all, in the hope to prevent abuse and possible vandalisms on SO?

### ٩(-̮̮̃-̃)۶ ٩(●̮̮̃•̃)۶ ٩(͡๏̯͡๏)۶ ٩(-̮̮̃•̃)

Should [it](https://superuser.com/questions/52671/how-do-i-create-unicode-smilies-like) be disallowed?

Comment: aight- I'm hooked. Which site did you go to to get those?

Comment: What vile vandalisms could be done with Unicode that could not be done with plain ASCII text?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/52671/how-do-i-create-unicode-smilies-like

Comment: @Grace I think we are going to see some *creativity* in this topic.

Comment: ... should I be upvoting or downvoting?

Comment: I changed the question from *forbid* to *allow* so you guys don't kill all my rep points because of it. Thank you.

Comment: Suggesting edits to answers for +2/answer after editing the question? Brilliant!

Comment: Actually, we need auto-link support for Unicode URLs! http://☃.net

Comment: @raven did you do that by hand?

Comment: Vote down means forbid unicode, vote up... allow it!

Comment: @Kop Why did you rollback? Am I not allowed to ask what I want? The question has been like that for 4 months already, what do you think justifies a rollback at this point? When you finish playing with my question could you please revert it to the way I left it? Thanks.

Comment: @karl: no, you are not allowed to invert the meaning of your question. If you want to do that you have to open a new question.

Comment: @Kop If I do that the question will be closed as EXACT DUPLICATE. I'm pretty sure the people that contributed to this thread don't mind, else I would have heard from them months ago.

Comment: @karl: /shrug. I reverted it back but as a rule of thumb you can't do what you did.. Otherwise the answers no longer make sense (like mine, which is the reason I reverted it)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No.

- Banning Unicode would make globalization of the sites impossible, so at best this could only be temporary.
- Using a white- or blacklist for allowed/disallowed characters is extremely problematic.
- The community handles spam on its own very quickly either by editing it out, or flagging.
- As a potential abuse of the system, posts with this content can be seen by, or reported to, moderators who can penalty-box users as appropriate for repeated offences.

Answer (score 15):

## ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃

٩(●̮̮̃•̃)۶ Forbid unicode ?

```
┃╲       ┃ ┏━━┓
┃  ╲     ┃ ┃   ┃
┃    ╲   ┃ ┃   ┃
┃      ╲ ┃ ┗━━┛
```

## ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃ ☃

Comment: I say we ☢ them.

Comment: We "soccer ball" them?

Comment: @bobobobo: No, you’re confusing `☢  U+02622 RADIOACTIVE SIGN` with `⚽  U+026BD SOCCER BALL`. There are lots of other balls, too, like `  U+1F3C8 AMERICAN FOOTBALL`, `  U+1F52E CRYSTAL BALL`, `  U+1F30D EARTH GLOBE EUROPE-AFRICA`, `  U+1F30E EARTH GLOBE AMERICAS`, `  U+1F30F EARTH GLOBE ASIA-AUSTRALIA`, and even `  U+1F383 JACK-O-LANTERN`. Whether `⚤ U+026A4 INTERLOCKED FEMALE AND MALE SIGN` goes in the balled category, I leave up to your (in)discretion — and perhaps the `  U+1F51E NO ONE UNDER EIGHTEEN SYMBOL`.  *    ?*

Comment: @tchrist those are *so* cool.

Comment: All spheres show as boxes!

Answer (score 15):

.

Z̵̬̮̫̞̪͖͔̖ͩ͐̓͌̓̍ͬA̝̺̗̜̯̱ͣ͐͆́Ḽ̷͚̼̠̘͎̈̀̂̋ͅĜ̩͚̲͕ͯ̚͢͡Ò̷̜̼̲̻̑͘͢ ̬̤̭̗̲̗̺ͫ͋͝W̵͈͔͎̞̠̲̯͌̌̾́I͔͓ͪͥ̆ͩͬ̀ͫ͑̐͘͠Ḷ̤͉̓͐͐̎̒́L̖̟ͤ̌̅ͬ̂̀̕ ̟̥̣̼̥͒ͧͮͬ͒̋ͥ͒͝C̜̥̱̘̗͓͍͔̓̒ͭ͐̇͜O̵̙̰̖͓͐̇̑̋ͩ̄͡M͊ͩ͆͊͏̰̫̭̳̼̠͎͡͝E̿͆͏̞͞
̧̛̰͚̜̘̞̫̹͉̈́̽͒͒̂͐ͮ͋̍͘
̧̞̙̗̪̳̍̐̀̌ͨ͜D̗̼̾̾O̘̠̓ͯ̀ͬ ̛̼̩̮͔ͣ̊͒̿̏ͭ̆N͇̥̤̯̮̣̖̖ͣ̓ͫͨÔ̴̢̯̼͕̮̺̰̗̓ͤͯͅT̘̈́̎͐̃ ̸̨͉̩̟̇͂͗͢À͉̜̝̥̝͎͉̗̔ͦ̊̓͐͟N̫͙͙̙͇̯͙͕̏͌ͥͤͥͦ͐͒̃̕G̣͚̖͚̱͎ͣ̓͛̎ͭ̄́E̹̝̣͚̹̗̻͉ͪR͍̗͙̹͑̓͟ ̫̥̤̖̳̼͕̯ͪͮ̌ͮͦ͡Zͩ͊͐̍́̋͏͚̬̦͕̫̙̩A̷͕̗̘̬͍͛̍ͭͣͫͭ̚͢ͅL̢̖̠̫̍ͦ͂̂ͭ̄͛G̖̙͙͓̺ͨ̆ͬO̵̹̫͚͉͈̣͖̔͗ͮ

.

Comment: Cool, where did you get this from?

Comment: Z̶̵̶̨A̶̴̢̧L̨̀G̷̢̧͡O̶̵͘͝ ̴́͟͞D̷͝͡O̕͜͟͡E̛͘͡S͜͟ ̵͘͘͟Ǹ̶̛͠O̶͢͢Ţ̕͝ ̡̨̛͞͝È̢̧͘͝X̶̵̢͝͡P̶̨͢͢͠O̵̷̕͠S͘͏E͏̨̢͢͠ ̸̨̀H̛̀͞Í͡S̀̀́ ͠S̨͞E̷̢͢͜C̢͝҉R͡͏̢̕̕È̶̕͢T̵̶͝S̶͘͢͏

Comment: http://www.eeemo.net/ ;)

Comment: And just in case: this [should kind of look like this](http://i.imgur.com/FM9PO.png).

Comment: @Arjan: Why doesn't it render like that for me? I'm using the latest Chrome on OSX. Do you need to have a specific font installed?

Comment: @yoda, probably you'll have to remove/disable fonts. Microsoft fonts installed with Office (trials) are not Unicode ready, or not in the way a Mac expects them to be. Go into Font Book, and find warnings of "multiple copies installed". Right-click, Resolve duplicates might already fix it. Or hit Command-I to toggle More Info, and try to figure out which font is the culprit... (If you're actually using Office then you might need to be careful. You can always enable again, of course.) See also http://word.mvps.org/mac/disable-fonts.html for some lists of fonts.

Comment: ugh! microsoft bummer again! Thanks for the info, will try it soon @Arjan

Answer (score 10):

No. We � Unicode!

Comment: We question Unicode?

Comment: *wooooosh* hehe :)

Comment: http://www.zazzle.com/i_unicode_tshirt-235442613480103840

Comment: If you’re really going to use *"We \N{UNICODE REPLACEMENT CHARACTER} Unicode!"*, don’t pretend it’s saying something it isn’t, you know. There are lots of better hearts: [uninames heart](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uninames) reveals ♡  02661, ♥ 02665, ❣ 02763, ❤  02764, ❥ 02765, ❦  02766, ❧ 02767,   1F491,   1F493,   1F494,   1F495,   1F496,   1F497,   1F498,   1F499,   1F49A,   1F49B,   1F49C,   1F49D,   1F49E,   1F49F,   1F60D, and   1F63B. Just because you can’t see them doesn’t mean they’re [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

Comment: And once again I am penalized for somebody else’s UTF‑16 buglet where they forgot to count characters correctly. How aggravating!  And oh by the way, and if you’re somebody who still needs [George Douros’s Symbola font for Unicode 6.0](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/), well gee now you know where to find it.   ¡λɐp ƨnolnqɐɟ ɐ əʌɐɥ puɐ ƨdləɥ ƨᴉɥʇ ədoɥ

Answer (score 9):

**Of course** we should allow freakin' unicode.

Unicode support was such a big deal 10 years ago.  Removing support represents an enormous step backwards, for no good reason. How can you have a **programming site** that doesn't even support Unicode in 2011?

This is an awful question the way it is stated, if anything an ASCII diagramming toolkit should be created to create ASCII tables and the like, for use in ASCII diagrams.  Plus [it would break this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Surprisingly some high-end programs such as [Autodesk Maya](https://area.autodesk.com/forum/autodesk-maya/modeling/3d-text-of-asian-characters-possible/) still have problems with Unicode today. Although the issue does only affect a relatively small number of use-cases, it still is a "bag of worms" (in the words of the poster at the link above) for those users that it does affect.

Answer (score 8):

While you like to play with unicode's less used parts, do remember that å, ä and ö are unicode characters too. Banning these would make a whole bunch of people angry... :)

Comment: So are many math symbols.

Comment: So too are many quote marks, currency symbols, subscripts, punctuation, and much more. People still living in an ASCII world are so out of it I don’t even have a ready metaphor to describe their bassackwardness. If you run `unichars -ga '[\p{Common}\p{Inherited}]' '[^\pM\pC\pZ]' 'NFD !~ /\p{ASCII}/' ` using my *utilísimo y celebérrimo* [unichars script](http://training.perl.com/scripts/unichars) from my [Unicode toolbox](http://training.perl.com/scripts/), you’ll find **6,110** useful code points in Unicode 6.0, not counting Han or Hangul even, but just plain `Common` type characters!