# Replacement character being used question URL

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, unicode

Some questions, for example

[What is the '😋' character?](https://superuser.com/q/516363)

Instead of using a correct URL, such as

```
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79543/٩●̮̮̃-̃۶-forbid-unicode
```

are using

```
https://superuser.com/questions/516363/what-is-the-��-character
```

What is causing this behavior?

Comment: The Meta post URL `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79543/٩●̮̮̃-̃۶-forbid-unicode` is not a valid URL either. I'm not saying the replacement characters are any more valid, but anything outside the ASCII range would have to be encoded in a URL. *Browsers* may elect to *display* decoded characters though.

Comment: E.g. the correct *current* URL is `http://superuser.com/questions/516363/what-is-the-%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd-character`. The Meta post URL is `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79543/%d9%a9%e2%97%8f%cc%ae%cc%ae%cc%83-%cc%83%db%b6-forbid-unicode`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Stack Exchange Title-to-URL-slug converter cannot handle characters outside the [BMP (the Basic Multilingual Plane)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), running from U+0000 through to U+FFFF.

The character in question, [U+1F60B](http://codepoints.net/U+1F60B), is [encoded to UTF-16 using a surrogate pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2B010000_to_U.2B10FFFF) instead, so you get [U+D83D](http://codepoints.net/U+D83D) [U+DE0B](http://codepoints.net/U+DE0B), and those are not 'displayable' (not valid Unicode) and get replaced by two [U+FFFD characters](http://codepoints.net/U+FFFD) on conversion to UTF-8.

The correct UTF-8 conversion would be `F0 9F 98 8B`, so the URL *should* be:

```
http://superuser.com/questions/516363/what-is-the-%f0%9f%98%8b-character
```

which my browser then happily displays as

```
http://superuser.com/questions/516363/what-is-the--character
```

(if an Emoji is displayed depends on your font and OS).